# How to get rid of this ClassNotFoundException that is encountered in my Android app only in debug mode?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, exception

I am using Google Play Location Services in my Android app and while debugging it, the code execution stops at this ClassNotFoundException instead of the breakpoints that I have set. The class in question (ParcelableGeofence) seems to belong to the Location Services API. I had added the Google Play Services library strictly following the instructions in the documentation and the app runs fine on the phone - this problem occurs only in the debug mode.

I have double checked to make sure that Google Play library project is present in Eclipse workspace as a library, is referenced by my project and the play services jar is present in the libs folder of my project. What else can we try to fix this issue or work around it? I am not able to debug other code because this error suspends the VM while debugging.

Please see the image of my debug perspective for this error below:

[image]

**EDIT**: To clarify, this error occurs when I debug on my phone that has the latest version of Google Play Services installed. So this does not have to do with the emulator not having the Play Services SDK.

Comment: check Google play services library version & your device Google play service version

Answer (score 1):

Source not found clearly tells you that the source code of the class is not available to show during debugging.  Google Play location services api library jar will have only the class files. Not the exact java source file.  So you cannot step into Google Play location services api method while u debug.  You need to step over and can debug only your methods. 
I would suggest you to check the return from Google Play location services library methods and then search Google with the returned error code or exception. 
Hope this will help you.

While you run the the projects,  just the byte code is enough.  No need of source code.

Note: If you wanna debug Android source code then install Android source code from SDK manager.  I would suggest you to install documentation also from SDK manager to understand Android api methods.

Comment: The problem is that I have set breakpoints on a completely different piece of code that has to do with Google Cloud Endpoints, still the code execution stops at some line related to Google Play Services. The debugger should automatically step over those lines. How can we avoid seeing this exception in the first place? It is making debugging very difficult.

Comment: Ideally It should not stop there. But have you tried to stepover ?

Comment: Try to keep a breakpoint in your code and dont try to go step by step when there is an external library codes comes in the middle.

Comment: Sorry, Couldnt update previous comment after 5 mins. Here is the continuation - Just jump to the next breakpoint incase of external code in between. Last point, Even if it shows source not found, Try to step over and you will reach the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does this, sometimes, when debugging Android projects. It used to be far more common a few years ago (e.g. when debugging Android 2.2 applications it would almost always occur on launch).

However, it has no effect other than being annoying (i.e. the app does *not* crash), just resuming execution should work.

If you breakpoints are not triggered, it's probably unrelated to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use GenyMotion emulator and install gapps

http://www.genymotion.com/

for gapps

https://goo.im/gapps/ (allows you to work on maps )

Answer (score 1):

I often notice ClassNotFoundExceptions when debugging Android Applications.
These exceptions mainly do not cause Apps to break as it is the Class - definition
which is requested and the related class may not get instantiated nessecarily.
So though it is a good idea in general to catch and avoid any exceptions,
in this case it is not of major concern. The error may result from an
unused import left in code related to a different android version,
or the class maybe instantiated only when run on a lower / higher target version.
Simple answer: Ignore it!

Answer (score 0):

VM don't support all of the features. You must debug in real device.

Comment: He's using a Nexus 4, as he states. That _is_ a real device! :)

Comment: @matiash didn't see the "bounty" part...but it may be nexus 4 emulator :P

Answer (score 0):

1. Open AVD Manager (Window > Android Virtual Device Manager)
2. Create (or copy) virtual device
3. Select target: Google APIs...
4. Start your virtual device and check "com.google.android.gms" process is there.

Default virtual devices have no Google Play Services features.

---

If you cannot select Google APIs as target, try this.

1. Open Android SDK Manager (Window > Android SDK Manager)
2. Install Google APIs (ex: Andriod 4.4.2(API19) > Google APIs(ARM..))

Answer (score 0):

I've used the google API in a previous project and I remember that by default the emulator don't ship with the google service (gmail, maps, google play, etc) it's just plain Android. I think you must install the google service first in your emulator or try to debug on a device that has the google service installed (it's probably there by default on physical devices).. I hope this helps!

Also it would help to see the actual error code.
If I remember correctly I think emulators cannot use the google's maps API because they require to be OpenGL capable which they are not..

Answer (score 0):

First as *Amav M* said:

> VM don't support all of the features. You must debug in real device.

You can also use the [blustacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) emulator, it has google services in it.

Second, you need to understand where this error is coming from. When your code reach a class that contains reference to undefined class(in your example it's emulator that does not have google services installed), the application will crush, it does not crush when you first use the class, but when it been accessed threw the imports. This is why you will not get a row number in your debugger.

To work around, either use a real device or **blustacks**, or test if google services is enabled and if not do not use any classes that import anything from google services apis.

To test if class exist:

```
public boolean isClassExist(String className) {
    try {
        return Class.forName(className) != null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```